Only-data messages being collapsed and dropped in iOS
I want to send multiple data messages to my flutter app. I was working with notifications as they were sent in all states (foreground, background, terminated) but found that they are being collapsed. I switched to use only-data messages and after some code modification, it works flawlessly on Android when the app is in any condition, I always receive the data message. Even if the user has no internet connection and multiple messages are sent, each one will be received after reconnecting. When testing this on iOS, I ran the app in release mode as I did in Android and everything worked in foreground, when I tried to swipe to home and send app to background and send a message, nothing is received. When I reopen the app, the data message is then received. If I send multiple data messages, only the last one is received after reopening the app.

This behaviour also exists when simply locking the iPhone

There are 2 major problems here:
1- Data messages are not being received in background/terminated states in release mode but works fine in profile mode
2- Even after re-opening the app, only the last data message is being received (similar to collapsing notifications in FCM)
I didn't find any comments regarding this behaviour in FCM doumentation. Can someone look into this to ensure if this is a normal behaviour or not. If so, how can I overcome it or a work around ?
Data Message Sending Function:
public function sendDataMessage($deviceTokens, $data = [], $priority = "high")
{
    $messaging = app('firebase.messaging');
    $clean_data = $data;
    if (isset($data["type"]) && $data["type"] == "chat" && $data["action"] == "receiveMessage") {
        unset($clean_data["fcm_message"]);
    }
    $messages = [];
    foreach ($deviceTokens as $token) {
        try {
            if (isset($data["type"]) && $data["type"] == "chat" && $data["action"] == "receiveMessage") {
                $chat_message = $data["fcm_message"];
                $clean_data["title"] = Chats::select("name")->find($data["chat_id"])->name;
                $clean_data["body"] = $chat_message["sender"]["name"] . ": " . ($chat_message["content"]["type"] == "Text" ? $chat_message["content"]["body"] : $chat_message["content"]["type"]);
            }
            $messages[] = CloudMessage::withTarget('token', $token)
                ->withData($clean_data)
                ->withAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig::fromArray([
                    'priority' => 'high',  // Use high priority
                    'ttl' => 86400 * 28, // 4 weeks in seconds
                ]))
                ->withApnsConfig(ApnsConfig::fromArray([
                    'headers' => [
                        'apns-expiration' => strval(time() + 86400 * 28), // Expiry timestamp
                        'apns-priority' => '10',
                    ],
                    'payload' => [
                        'aps' => [
                            // 'sound' => 'default',
                            "content-available" => 1,
                            "mutable-content" => 1
                        ],
                    ],
                ]));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e;
        }
    }
    try {
        $report = $messaging->sendAll($messages);
    } catch (NotFound $e) {
        return $e;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e;
    }

    return $report->successes()->count();
}

Firebase Handler:
static void initializeFCMHandler() async {
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleBackgroundMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(handleMessage);
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
static Future<void> handleBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage? message) async {
    if (message?.notification != null) {
      handleNotification(message, isBackground: true);
    } else {
      handleDataMessage(message, isBackground: true);
    }
}

static void handleMessage(RemoteMessage? message) async {
    if (message?.notification != null) {
      handleNotification(message);
    } else {
      handleDataMessage(message);
    }
}


Have you enabled the appropriate background mode in your Xcode project for your iOS app?  The behaviour is nothing to do with FCM,  but rather the underlying APNS.  Content-available messages are throttled when the app is in the background. You should expect to receive no more than a few per hour. They are not intended to be used to send data to your app. They are to tell your app that there is new data for it to fetch. No notification system has guaranteed delivery.

I did enable background fetch and remote notification. I understand that No notification system has guaranteed delivery. but the problem here is that background handler is not working at all with data messages. but once the user re-opens the app, the last data message is then sent and handled by onMessage handler. Why does this happen @Paulw11

How are you signing your release mode build? Is it still signed as a developer release or is it an ad-hoc or App Store signed build?  For the latter you must make sure that you are using the production apns ens point, not the sandbox.

Actually you were correct, apple only allows for a few number of background messages to be delivered, after that there is a cooldown for background fetch.
